# Make unit tests with dates pass in all time zones and with/out DST

Tags: java, unit-testing, timezone

How do I make this unit test pass in all time zones independent of whether DST is active or not?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    private final static SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm.ss:SSSZZ" );

    @Test
    public void testUtilDateMillis() throws Exception {
        assertEquals( "1970.01.01T00:00.00:000+0000", DATE_FORMAT.format( new Date( 0L ) ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void testDateTimeMillis() throws Exception {
        assertEquals( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00", new DateTime( 0L ).toString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, a new `SimpleDateFormat` will use the system default time zone. If you want a specific time zone, you should call `setTimeZone` on it:

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = createFormat();

private static SimpleDateFormat createFormat() {
    // Make sure there are no locale-specific nasties, either...
    SimpleDateFormat ret = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm.ss:SSSZZ",
                                                Locale.US);
    ret.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
}
```

For your second test, you'd want to change it to:

```
new DateTime(0L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Note that you shouldn't usually use a static `SimpleDateFormat` variable, as it's not thread-safe. (Whereas the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) `DateTimeFormatter` implementation *is* thread-safe.)

Comment: I fixed the time strings. They now expect midnight as they should.

Comment: I don't want to change the `new DateTime(0L)`. But setting the locale+timezone on the joda-time formatter also fixes the issue.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Sure - I was assuming you wanted to just call toString. If you're going to allow a DateTimeFormatter, life becomes a lot nicer :)

Answer (score -3):

Or you can compare the date and put

```
@Ignore("Timezone issues")
@Test
```

In your unit-test

Comment: That will ignore the whole test.