# Time-independent JUnit Test Cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, date, junit, jodatime

I have a Util class with 1 method which calculates age using joda-time:

```
public static int getAge(LocalDate birthdate) {
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
    Period period = new Period(birthdate, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
    return period.getYears();
}
```

I've written an extensive JUnit test class but how do I make it time-independent? If I create a test case to calculate someone's age if they were born today in 1970 then the result would be 46 years old. But 1 year from now if i run the test case it would fail because the result would be 47.

So how do I make these test cases time-independent. I was thinking of having some sort of calendar interface that the test cases would create a date object from. I also stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846704/how-do-i-write-unit-tests-to-make-sure-my-date-time-based-code-works-for-all-tim) post which is another possible solution to this but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

A common practice (described in the book Growing Object Oriented Software guided by Tests) is to delegate the responsability of creating the date instance to a collaborator.

Imagine you have a class like this:

```
public class Clock {
  public LocaleDate now(){
    return  new LocalDate();
  }
}
```

then your code could become

```
public static int getAge(LocalDate birthdate, Clock clock) {
    LocalDate today = clock.now();
    Period period = new Period(birthdate, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
    return period.getYears();
}
```

I would be fine not testing `Clock#now` as it is trivially correct, but I can now pass in a mocked clock instance to test the `getAge` method.

Now this means a class using the static `getAge` must provide a clock, the clock would be a dependency for this class. Such dependencies can be injected in various mockable ways.

I personnally am of the `injection by constructor` school, but anything from `injection by reflection` to proctected factory method (which can therefore be overloaded in an anonymous subclass used to create a test instance) works.

This problem and the design I suggest are discussed at length in [the book](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/), in many [blog posts](https://www.google.fr/search?q=testing+time+dependant+code) and in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622194/time-dependent-unit-tests) (it looks like java 8 has [direct support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464938/7898) for it if you are willing to move to java.time)

Answer (score 3):

Use fixed date :

```
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate(2016, 1, 5);
```

Comment: Wow....I'm not sure why I didn't think of this......the most obvious solution...thank you

Comment: actually this doesn't work now that I think about it because the `new LocalDate` is inside the getAge function and I can't hardcode a value in there. It has to be current date when in production use. So I'm wondering if there's some sort of way to replace that using `Mockito.when`

Comment: You can very well use `Mockito.when`. Or you can override the `getAge` method to return static date for your test case, if permitted.

Comment: i would rather go the `Mockito.when` route but I'm not sure how to implement that in this case.

Answer (score 1):

So, first let me say I agree with `Jean`. However I have found that this pattern is so common I have implemented a reusable solution in a library on GitHub called LibEx. It is called `DateSupplier`. To get the current `DateTime` you use `DateSupplier.getCurrentDateTime()`. Then in the tests you use a `@Rule DateController` which allows for `datController.setCurrentDateTo...()`. When this is set in a test the `DateSupplier` will return the value as specified by the `DateController`.

Here are the links:

- [DateSupplier](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/9d826f725e49893e229a8f576a072e8777739284/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/DateSupplier.java)
- [DateController](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/9d826f725e49893e229a8f576a072e8777739284/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/concurrent/DateController.java)
- [DateControllerTest](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/9d826f725e49893e229a8f576a072e8777739284/testlibex/src/test/java/org/libex/test/concurrent/DateControllerTest.java)

Your test would then look like this..

```
public class DateControllerTest extends TestBase {

@Rule
public DateController dateContoller = new DateController();

@Test
public void testSetCurrentTime() {
    // setup
    Date date = new Date(123443);

    // test
    dateContoller.setCurrentTime(date);

    // verify
    assertDateEquals(date);
}

private void assertDateEquals(Date date) {
    assertThat(DateSupplier.getCurrentDate(), equalTo(date));
    assertThat(DateSupplier.getCurrentDateInMilliseconds(), equalTo(date.getTime()));
}
```

Because `DateController` is a `Rule`, it will reset to the default behavior after each test. Also, `DateController` is in the `libex-test` module that should be test scoped, so it is in deployed in your production code.

Answer (score -1):

So you want the birthdate of someone turning 46 today? (Your question is not clear.)

## java.time

The makers of Joda-Time tell us to move to using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later as soon as is comfortable.

```
ZonedDateTime birthdateOf46YearOld = ZonedDateTime.now().minusYears( 46 );
```

This object is implicitly assigned the JVM’s current default time zone. I recommend always being explicit with your time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or… ZoneOffset.UTC …or… ZoneId.systemDefault().
ZonedDateTime birthdateOf46YearOld = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ).minusYears( 46 );
```

Or do you want to test if a date-time value in hand is the same as that birthdate?

```
Boolean hit = someZdt.isEqual( birthdateOf46YearOld );
```

If you care only about date without time-of-day or time zone, then use `LocalDate`, similar to Joda-Time. Note that time zone is crucial in determining today’s date as it varies across time zones around the globe.

```
LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).minusYears( 46) ;
```

If you simply want the elapsed time in years between a pair of LocalDate objects, use the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
LocalDate birthDate = … ;
Period period = Period.between( birthDate , today );
Integer ageInYears = period.getYears();
Boolean hit = ageInYears.equals ( Integer.valueOf( 46 ) ) ;
```

## Joda-Time

If Java 8 or later is not available to you, the same kind of code works in Joda-Time.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime birthdate = DateTime.now( zone ).minusYears( 46 );
```

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.