# Python 2.7.8: Different values of fromtimestamp on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, datetime

Python 2.7.8, I call:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(10)
```

But there are different results depending on operating system:

- 1970-01-01 01:00:10 - Linux
- 1970-01-01 00:00:10 - Windows

So there is one hour shift. Is this a known issue? Is there any way to unify returned value, so that result is same on different OSes?

Comment: If you only want comparable timestamps, [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) gives you seconds since the Epoch. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186179/in-python-is-epoch-time-returned-by-time-always-measured-from-jan-1-1970) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the two operating systems had different timezone settings.

The python standard library does not make available an implementation of timezone (as written in [the python's documentation for tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo)). Anyway you should use the third-party (pure-python) [pytz module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) like in the following code.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('America/St_Johns')
datetime.fromtimestamp(10, tz)
```

Comment: The same happens here as the OP, with Python 3.5, and both Ubuntu and Windows 10 set to the London time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any timezone differences?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Have a look at the tzinfo in the datetime library docs, I wonder if that is different