# how to covert date to milisecond in python

Tags: python

I have a date in this format 04-07-2018
the following Javascript produces

```
const date1 = new Date("04-07-2018").getTime();
date1; // 1523084400000
```

how do I parse the date  and convert them to milliseconds in python

Comment: Might be already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can perform this in three steps:

1. first we convert the string to a `datetime` object;
2. next we calculate the difference between that `datetime` object and the first of January, 1970;
3. we calculate this difference in seconds, and then multiply it with 1000.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def total_millis(text):
    dt = datetime.strptime(text, '%m-%d-%Y')
    return 1000 * (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

This implementation however is timezone independent, whereas the JavaScript version depends on the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.

You can use `datetime` but you should compute it with a `deltatime` object since according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186179/in-python-is-epoch-time-returned-by-time-always-measured-from-jan-1-1970) Python doesn't guarantee any particular epoch time

```
import datetime
delta = datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 7) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
milliseconds = delta.total_seconds()*1000 # 1523059200000.0
```